# Can Apache Kafka be used with C++?

Tags: c++, image, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Apache Kafka. Kafka documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction) mentions that it can be used with C++. But i am not sure how to do that. My application continuously generates image files and need to be transferred to another machine. I felt i could use stream api of Kafka but not sure how to stream image files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Apache Kafka with C/C++.

By far the most popular C/C++ client is https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.  You can use the client to read data from Kafka and write data back to Kafka.

Further documentation on librdkafka is available at http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/index.html (the author of librdkafka, Magnus Edenill, works at Confluent).

Comment: I needed Kafka for C++ on Windows but looks like currently, it doesn't support Windows platform. Is any alternative there?

Comment: @user2504641 librdkafka (C/C++) is supported on Windows. Just reference the librdkafka.redist package from your Visual studio project.

Comment: Also check out some examples here https://github.com/perkss/c-kafka-examples